# uwsgi server gives 'AUTH_USER_MODEL has not been installed' where django runserver does not

Tags: django, uwsgi

I have a uWSGI + Nginx set up that is producing the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.CustomUser' that has not been installed
```

The error message is showing that virtualenv is picked up fine, as are other apps within my project `apps/` folder.

If I run the same site via `django-admin.py runserver` then the error does not occur.

Comment: Is the `wsgi.py` (for deployment) using the same settings as your `manage.py` (for development)?

Comment: Yes, both are setting `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings_local")` which in turn imports `from default.settings import *` which is where `AUTH_USER_MODEL=accounts.CustomUser` is set. I've read that this error can sometimes occur when an import fails, however I've no idea how to prove this within uWSGI.

Comment: Maybe the PYTHON_PATH is different. Have you added your project's path properly to the WSGI environment?

Comment: I would say the PYTHON_PATH is adequate as part of the stack trace calls a line from `apps/registration/models.py`, and the `accounts.CustomUser` in question is defined in `apps/accounts/models.py`

Comment: The only bell this error rings to me is failure to include the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` or the app itself being incapable of loading properly (due to import errors, in `models.py` for instance) Since it goes well with `runserver`, maybe it's an external package that is not installed in your deployment server?? Other than that, and without more info, I'm spent :(

Comment: Thanks for your help in any case. Both uwsgi and runserver are being tested on the same server, so I'm doubtful package differences are the culprit. This is weird.